# Nested Serializer for prefetch_related in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-prefetch-related

I'm trying to make a nested serializer with `prefetch_related` but it doesn't work, here's my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Student(models.Model):
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student")


class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')


class CourseEnroll(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='course_enroll')
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='student_enroll')
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet

from quiz.models import Course
from quiz.serializers import CourseSerializer


class CourseViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    GenericViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Course.objects.prefetch_related("course_enroll").all()
        return queryset
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from quiz.models import Course, CourseEnroll


class CourseEnrollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CourseEnroll
        fields = ['id']


class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    student_enrolled = CourseEnrollSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'student_enrolled']
```

Here's my repo:
https://github.com/congson95dev/regov-pop-quiz-backend-s-v1

Did I do something wrong here? Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) does not create a nested serialization. Rather it is used to cache the related model fields, so that when the queryset is executed, it does not make additional DB calls.

Here, you are using `student_entrolled` pointing to `CourseEnrollSerializer`, which won't work because of wrong field name. It should be:

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    course_enroll = CourseEnrollSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'course_enroll']
```

Comment: thanks for reply, you mean i should change from `student_entrolled` to `course_enroll` in serializers.py and it will be work?

Comment: Yes, just like you have defined in your model (using related_name)

Comment: oh, so it should be the same name as `related_name` in model.

Comment: Yes, if not you can explicitly mention [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

Comment: thanks, i'll check about this next morning. Also, can you pls help me on this one too?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75930160/how-to-override-createsuperuser-command-in-django